# Help understanding coordinates

Tags: coordinate-system, reprojection-mathematics

I am trying to use this lightning data set. https://www.ncei.noaa.gov/thredds/dodsC/lightning/countPerYear_Aggregation.ncml.html
i do not understand the coordiante system which was used in generating the dataset. I want to understand how to convert a simple lat, long in WGS84 into the coordinate system used to generate the dataset.

```
PROJCS["NAD83 / Texas Centric Albers Equal Area",

GEOGCS
["NAD83",DATUM
  ["North_American_Datum_1983",SPHEROID
  ["GRS1980",6378137,298.257222101],
  TOWGS84[0,0,0]
],


PRIMEM
["Greenwich",0,AUTHORITY["EPSG","8901"]],
UNIT["degree",0.01745329251994328,AUTHORITY["EPSG","9122"]],
AUTHORITY["EPSG","4269"]],



UNIT["metre",1,AUTHORITY["EPSG","9001"]],
PROJECTION["Albers_Conic_Equal_Area"],
PARAMETER["standard_parallel_1",27.5],
PARAMETER["standard_parallel_2",35],
PARAMETER["latitude_of_center",18],
PARAMETER["longitude_of_center",-100],
PARAMETER["false_easting",1500000],
PARAMETER["false_northing",6000000],
AUTHORITY["EPSG","3083"],
AXIS["X",EAST],AXIS["Y",NORTH]]
```

institution: National Climatic Data Center (http://www.ncdc.noaa.gov)
source: generated using SwdiGridder (version trunk) by Mark Phillips  from input file: ../csv/nldn-2011.csv
history: generated on Fri Dec 28 21:00:49 EST 2012

How can I understand this coordinate system of this dataset?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Pasting your `.prj` into http://prj2epsg.org/search gives [EPSG:3083](http://prj2epsg.org/epsg/3083), armed with that information almost any desktop gis will be able to convert your lat/lon data to that projection.